# How do you use inline stylesheets in coldfusion with unique element IDs?

Tags: coldfusion

I'm getting errors because CF doesn't like the # that I would normally use to notate a style applied to an ID:

```
<style>
#someid { somestyle}
</style>
```

I tried doubling the hash, but it didn't make any difference. I can't find any documentation or articles about this either. What's the secret!?

Comment: Certainly a valid question, but this has been answered before, ex. [Treat a # in ColdFusion output as just text and not a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16866039/treat-a-in-coldfusion-output-as-just-text-and-not-a-variable). Escaping is also mentioned [in the docs](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/the-cfml-programming-language/elements-of-cfml/special-characters.html) *"...number sign (#) characters have special meaning to ColdFusion. To include [..] in a string, double the character; for example, use ## to represent a single # character."*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use double `##`

```
<style>
##someid { somestyle}
</style>
```

Comment: Oh man... I'm such a moron. I forgot to sync the offline files to the server and that's why the changes weren't working. Your answer is correct and I'll accept it in a few minutes when the system lets me. I'll leave this question if only because I couldn't find any other definitive posts about it so it wouldn't hurt to have one.